# Как получить ссылку на фрагмент карты Google api Staticmap в формате PNG

Tags: yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Через google api staticmap, можно получить ссылку на фрагмент карты, то есть на картинку, но проблема в том, что в этой ссылке нет конкретного упоминания, что это картинка например png, jpeg.

Можно ли как-то получить другую ссылку на такой же фрагмент карты только с конкретным названием, что этот файл картинка?
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=640x640&visual_refresh=true&scale=2&center=30,0&zoom=2&maptype=roadmap

Вариант указать формат .png в конце ссылки - не работает. Это должно быть указано перед всеми вспомогательными символами, которые обозначают координаты и т. п. Знаю что у гугла есть свойство типо *format* png, это тоже не работает.

Например api staticmap Mapbox, есть упоминание, что это картинка, это в указано в перед первым знаком вопроса, и программа скачивает картинку. https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.emerald/-73.7638,42.6564,8/600x300@2x.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY5YzJzczA2ejIzM29hNGQ3emFsMXgifQ.az9JUrQP7klCgD3W-ueILQ

Тот же самый вопрос по Яндекс картам, они тоже без png и тоже не скачиваются https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?ll=37.620070,55.753630&size=600,450&z=13&l=map&amp

Помогите, пожалуйста, уже неделю с этим мучаюсь нигде ответа не могу найти.

Comment: Какой конкретно формат url нужен программе? Например, ничто не мешает добавить параметр с именем файла в запрос, google и yandex их просто игнорируют. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=640x640&visual_refresh=true&scale=2&center=30,0&zoom=2&maptype=roadmap&format=png&name=1.png` `https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?ll=37.620070,55.753630&size=600,450&z=13&l=map&amp&name=1.png`

Comment: Анатолий,спасибо за ответ. .PNG должен стоять перед первым знаком вопроса, как у мапбокса, так как после знака вопроса и идут всякие технические знаки для карты. К сожалению, вариант поставить .PNG, в конце ссылки не работает, об этом я написал в вопросе.

Comment: "Можно ли как-то получить другую ссылку на такой же фрагмент карты только с конкретным названием, что этот файл картинка?" Тогда получается, что нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Упоминание о том, что это картинка есть в HTTP-заголовке `Content-Type`.

В данном случае это `image/png`.

Обратите внимание, что при включенном кэшировании Яндекс может отдать вам заголовок `304 Not Modified` и `Content-Type: text/plain`. В таком случае тип контента вам нужно определить самостоятельно по закэшированному изображению или добавить случайный параметр в строку запроса.